# Countable range of sections of uncountably valued function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to find a function $f:X\times Y\to Z$ that has an uncountable image, but at the same is such that all the sections 
$X\to Z, x\mapsto f(x,g(x))$ have countable image, for any $g:X\to Y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{0\}, Y=Z=\Bbb R, f(x,y)=y$  The image is all of $\Bbb R$ but the sections are all a single point.  If you don't think finite sets are countable you should be able to patch this up.